# Smallest integer $x$ s.t. $x! \equiv 0 \pmod {216}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

By guess and check I found $x$ to be $9$, but is there a more general way to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Note that $216 = 6^3 = 2^3 \cdot 3^3$, so $n!$ must be divisible by $3$ three times. In particular, $n$ cannot be smaller than $9$, since $3$ and $6$ are the only multiples of $3$ less than $9$, contributing only two factors of three.

Answer (score 2):

216 is $6^3=2^33^3$

So, we need the first number by which we have 3 occurrences of the number 3, and 3 of the number 2. We get 3 occurrences of 2 by 4, we get three occurrences of 3 by 9, so the answer is 9.